# Difference between binary labeling and multi-labeling in energy minimization via graph-cut

Tags: stereo-3d, vision, disparity-mapping

I am working on graph cut to create disparity map from a stereo system but I still have problem to understand binary and multi-labeling I guess that they are both reduced to a binary problem but I can't see the difference

Thanks

Comment: This is very vague. This subject is still an active area of research with a rich litterature. As it is, your question is a bit like "I'm using math to solve an equation, but...". So I think you really need to give more details. What papers have you read? What cost functions do you plan on minimizing? What are the parametrizations? etc etc.

Comment: Plus, I would be surprised if the multi-label  case were always reduced to a binary problem. It would be cool if you could discuss that too.